# What if the Moderator Variable is correlated with the error term?

Tags: interaction, endogeneity

Is it possible for a moderator variable to be correlated with the error term?
Suppose I have a simple regression model as follows:

$y=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + u$

Now, if $x_1$ - the predictor variable - is correlated with the error term $u$, then I have an endogeneity problem. Does this problem get worse when I add another variable - lets say $z$ - to the regression and $z$ is my moderator variable. 
What if $z$ is also correlated with the error term?

To cut a long story short: can one deal with endogeneity problems by the use of moderator variables? Can these moderator variables themselves be a source of endogeneity?

Regarding feasible explanations: Are there any quotable sources available?

Comment: Wooldridge, in his book *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data*, would describe this correlation as evidence for the presence of endogeneity, as you note. His discussion on pps. 50 and 51 of the 2002 edition of that book suggests possible causes and remedies.